# iOS ViewController that supports all orientations changes to landscape after returning from landscape ViewController

Tags: ios, objective-c, orientation

I have a main ViewController that supports all device orientations, and a video player ViewController that supports landscape only.

When the device's orientation is unlocked, and I get back from a video to the main ViewController, it is still auto-rotating according to my device's orientation. This is the desired behaviour.

However when the device's orientation is locked, and I start with a portrait mode main ViewController, I get back from the landscape video and now the main ViewController is locked to landscape mode. This happens only on iOS 9+.

I'm not sure it's relevant but the main ViewController inherits Cordova's CDVViewController. Here is the orientation-related code from VideoPlayerViewController:

```
- (BOOL)shouldAutorotate{
    return YES;
}

- (NSInteger)supportedInterfaceOrientations{
    return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskLandscape;
}

- (UIInterfaceOrientation)preferredInterfaceOrientationForPresentation{
    return UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft;
}

- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation
{
    return (interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft ||
            interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight);
}
```

I would appreciate any ideas on how to solve this. Thanks!

Comment: How is the video view being presented...pushed onto a UINavigationController or as a modal view controller?

Answer (score 0):

I think it has to be `CDVViewController`s fault for changing orientation.

If you use a regular UIViewController with UIKit elements and device has orientation locked than it will never switch from Portrait to Landscape orientation while device has orientation lock ON.

For testing purpose, try and replacing `CDVViewController` with a regular UIViewController and just add a button to present `VideoPlayerViewController` and you whould see that it will stay in Portrait as expected.